# Are HTTP/1.0 status lines case sensitive or not?

Tags: http, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, rfc

I ran in to the following problem when correcting student assignments recently

the students had implemented a rudimentary web server and this solution sent back the status line in lower case like this

```
http/1.0 200 OK
```

It is not explicitly mentioned in RFC 1945 that this filed should be either case sensitive or insensitive, so how should one interpret the RFC in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol name in status line in HTTP/1.1 is case-sensitive (see http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7230.html#http.version).

The ancient 1.0 spec is indeed not clear, but the I'm pretty sure the intent was to make this case-sensitive, too.